# SysInfo usage doesn't change

Tags: c++

I have a question about sysinfo freeram usage. When I use it in my program it reports the same answer each time, which I would think it should be dynamic, not static. I plan to use it as test points throughout my program to determine bottlenecks.  Example stubbed out below:

test.h

`struct sysinfo meminfo;`

test.cpp

```
unsigned long iFreeMemory = 0;
iFreeMemory = meminfo.freeram;
std::cout "Free Ram: " << iFreeMemory << std::endl;
system( run any program.... );
iFreeMemory = meminfo.freeram;
std::cout << "Free Ram: " << iFreeMemory << std::endl;
etc...
```

The result is the same each time.  I would think that the answer should be different each time. Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually calling `sysinfo()`?  Your code looks like you don't.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long iFreeMemory = 0;
sysinfo( &meminfo );
iFreeMemory = meminfo.freeram;
std::cout << "Free Ram: " << iFreeMemory << std::endl;
```

You need to call 'sysinfo(&meminfo)' every time when you want to check the free memory.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect the free memory to change due to calling `system()`.  But that doesn't necessarily make sense, because whatever memory is used by the program you invoke with `system()` will be immediately reclaimed by the OS when that program terminates.  So before and after the `system()` invocation,  you'd expect the system memory utilization to be about the same.